# set Multiple titles to Different toolbars of different activities from base activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am using a base activity in which I have added a toolbar. Now I wish to set the toolbar.setTitle as per the Activity opened. I am unable to do so. ` View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView usernameTv = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.headerName);
usernameTv.setText(username);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

```
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, 0, 0);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    Context context = drawer.getContext();
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();`
```

Have pasted my code for reference. I have also implemented method onNavigationItemSelected for opening the activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, you need to set toolbar bar title `toolbar.setTile(R.string.title1)`? 
 
You can set variable int as an abstract variable on your base activity and implement this variable on your activities that extend Base Activity and you can set this variable with your strings on strings file like `R.string.title1` or `R.string.title2`

Comment: thanks, but I now used the below method.

After checking this further, I added the toolbar.setTitle and setSupportActionBar(toolbar) and then added the method onOptionsItemSelected in all the activities so that the hamburger click works.

The toolbar and the toggle are called from the base activity and not declared in other activities and it works perfectly now.